# Getting an array of values using get_query_vars

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Say i have an URL "http://example.com/result/?q=test1&color=blue&color=black"

I would like to get an array of values

Resulting in `q = test1;`and `color=[blue, black]`

I included my vars in functions.php

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    array_push($vars,"q","color");
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

But when i use get_query_vars i get only single value and not an array.

Is it even possible to get an array of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your URL with array syntax for parameters that are specified more than once. Note the square brackets:

```
http://example.com/result/?q=test1&color[]=blue&color[]=black
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [q] => test1
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => black
        )

)
```